# app on AndroidThings preview 5.1 doesn't reboot

Tags: android-things

I have several app that I am working on for AndroidThing. With preview 5.1 and RPI3, I image the SDcard with the 5.1 image.  I then install the apps from Android Studio (2.3.3).
1) One of the apps runs properly when downloaded.  But when I try to reboot the RPI3, the app doesn't restart and I just have the AndroidThings splash screen on my display.

2) I do the same process to load the second app (on a different SDcard).  This app runs for about one minute before it "crashes" and I end up again in the AndroidThings splash screen.  When I restart the RPI3 all I get is the AndroidThings splash screen.

Is this an issue with the 5.1 preview?  I have not tried it on 5.0.  On 4.1 I was not having this problem.  I had no crashes of the app and when I restarted the RPI3, the app started up.

I can't see any obvious error messages in the logs.

I'm going to see if I can try it on 5.0 but I had initial issues with 5.0 when it first came out and different run the apps on it.

Comment: can you show us the logs? Have you also ensured you only have a single apk installed on the devices?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your apps have a Home Activity declared with the `IOT_LAUNCHER` and `DEFAULT` categories in an intent filter as described in our [Getting Started tutorial](https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project.html). This tells Android Things which of your apps should be started automatically on boot.

You can only define one application on a given device to listen for this intent. Android Things will not start multiple apps this way. You may need to listen for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast in other apps on the device you need to launch automatically.

Comment: Thanks,  Discovered my issue for it not rebooting was that I didn't identify it as the DEFAULT (i.e. <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>.  I'm not sure if this was necessary in previous releases of the devpreview.

Comment: Yes, both have been required since the beginning. Apologies for not mentioning both in my answer here. Edited.